# Simplify a Coffeescript if /else

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a pretty simple If/else that I've put into coffeescript.

Everything works fine.  But I was wondering if there was a more concise way to write/approach it. (the comments are not actually in the code)

```
targets = subviewA.getATargets

#getBTargets will return an empty [] if no targets
#otherwise returns [Object]

if targets.length < 1
  targets = subviewB.getBTargets()
  #Same as getATargets returns an [Object]
else
  #If targets already has [Object] concat 
  targets = targets.concat subviewB.getBTargets()
```

This works (I also hadn't set up the subviews, just added the function which returns information) but it seems very cumbersome.  I'm relatively new to Coffeescript, so any information would be appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with `subviewA.getATargets.concat subviewB.getBTargets`? Empty array is the identity element for concatenation; `[].concat foo` is `foo`.

Comment: Apparently nothing.  Thanks for the info.

Guess I was over complicating it.